# Why am I getting MySQL 2003 error: Connection refused error?

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-2003, remote-mysql

I know that this is likely not the right place to ask this question but I am at a loss as to where else to go.  I signed up on remotemysql.com to create a (free) database.  The data that I store in there means a lot to me, and in the last day or so, I am no longer able to connect to the server (neither from MySQL Workbench nor a python application that wrote data to it).  The error I get is a `2003 error: connection refused`

I haven't changed my credentials at all and have not violated any of the terms and conditions.  Has anybody ever had this issue before? Or does anybody know how to get in touch with the maintainers of remotemysql to help troubleshoot?

Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: If this was working and now it isn't, something has changed. If you haven't changed anything then something at remotemysql.com has changed - you'd have to ask them. I note from their FAQ that if you don't INSERT or UPDATE data in a database you have there for 30 days, they'll delete the database. Just using SELECT isn't enough to prevent that.

Comment: This is truly no the place to ask for support regarding a service provided by a third party. Remotemysql.com is a free service for testing and development purposes only. They provide no support whatsoever and offer no warrantees or guarantees of any kind for uninterrupted availability of the service or the data. You should have kept an offline backup of your data. Not really sure what you expect from a free service...

Comment: Btw, connection refused hints at either a network configuration error or that the port number is incorrect or the target mysql server is not running at all.

Comment: Thanks @TangentiallyPerpendicular, appreciate your response.  I have been doing regular inserts.  I'd love to be able to ask them what changed on their end, or even find other users of the service, but I can't find a way to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is looking at this thread, my DB instance has been restored.  Not sure what happened and will probably never find out, but I guess this comes with the territory.